# Hold Frame in Compositor

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes

In my scene I have a text object I'm rendering over a photograph with nice natural depth of field. I am matching the depth of field effect with a defocus node in the compositor. Since the camera doesn't move for the duration of the sequence, I'd like to hold the first frame. Effectively rendering the defocus node for one frame and extending that frame in the VSE for the length of the sequence.

I do not want to render the frame out to a file and then import it back in. I will be doing this many time and want to avoid any manual two step process. I need a non-destructive way to do this in one step. In NUKE, this is a 'HoldFrame' node, in After Effect you can use TimeRempaing, FUSION also has a solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a input->image node and open the video file with it.
In the node controls you can set how many frames of your video file you want to use (frames), when to start in your composition (start frame), and the offset value is the one that will allow you to choose the exact frame to be used.
In this example the original quicktime file has 1600 frames but only 1 frame (797) will be displayed, as freeze frame, starting at frame 1 and for the entire length of the composition.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however this requires rendering the blurred text to an image and then re-importing that blurred text image with an image node. I need to be able to blur the text in the compositor and hold the blurred frame in the same project.

Comment: No, the text is being rendered directly but not saved to a file. The compositing is happening at the same time as the text is getting blurred and the images added behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Use image/movie input nodes for the rendered animation as it has frame variables like offset and current frame. You can animate them to pause at the correct time.

Comment: I'd like to keep the composite 'live'. Rendering the sequence first means I'd have to do this with each and every tweak I make. As I mentioned in the question: 'I do not want to render the frame out to a file and then import it back in.'