# chromakey overlay at end of video

Tags: compositing-nodes, video

Assume you want to put a green screen overlay *at the end* of a longer video clip. Blender doesn't allow to do this in the compositor mode, because the overlay is placed at the beginning.

Is it possible to easily add the overlay at the end of the video?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/how-can-i-make-a-movie-clip-node-start-at-a-certain-frame-of-the-scene/9123#9123

Comment: also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8985/1853

Answer (score 0):

duplicate the video strip on a new channel, add the overlay effect to it and delete the unnecessary parts at the beginning.

Comment: how is it possible to copy strips in the compositor? also: how does this solve my problem, because I don't know how to apply overlay at the end.

Comment: my answer is about the video sequence editor, you duplicate with Shift+D