# Movie clip node as mask

Tags: node-editor, masking

[image: Node editor]
I am trying to do something simple but i encountered a problem i can't resolve. I am using a movie clip node as a mask  which last 30 frames in the compositor. For the 30 first frames it works well but right after the 30th frame the movie disapear. I would like to make the last frame of the mask movie clip last to the last frame of the render movie.
[image: node editor]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a movie clip node use an Image Sequence node (you can also load videos in it)

Then you will have control of how many frames to use, at what point in time and offset.

To hold the last frame just untick the **Cycle** box

[image]

See these related links:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9123/1853

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8985/1853